# Reading Excel file on the server

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have asp.net application which loads excel file to read. It works fine on my local development server. However when I upload it to server it wont display the uploaded excel file.
I have MS Office installed on my local machine but not on server. 
Thanks for your guidance

The code I am using is...

```
if (fileExtension == ".xls")
            {
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\""; 
            }
            else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 14.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
            }
            //Create OleDB Connection and OleDb Command
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName +"]";
            dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
            con.Close();
            GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

I keep getting error

```
  " The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."
```

Even though I installed Access db and I can see ACE 14.0 still I keep getting this error

Comment: How're you reading the file? Is it an OLEDB connection? Can u show some code? Also what exactly is not working on the server - is it throwing an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the features of Excel you need you'll need to install Excel on server or the client, or a third party control(s) that understand the format.

1. If the application is WEB application where the application actually showing the data locally on the client via a web brower : See this MS link : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059. Here you're actually sending the xls file/stream to the client.
2. If you are showing it a WEB application, and shows data on the web page where the rendered content is sent to the client then you need [Excel Services](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-excel-services-and-excel-web-access-HA010105476.aspx) on the server (I think this is part of the SharePoint family), or a third party AS.NET control that ready .XLS info and renders it into the page.
3. If the application is a desktop application that shows excel data in stand alone app where the user logs into the server as a desktop user then you need to have Excel installed on the server. Or you need  third party .net control (dependant on app technology WinForms, WFP/Silverlight etc) that can read the .XLS info and present it.
4. If the application is running on a virtual desktop, say like Citrix, then it's the same as 3.
5. **If all you're doing is reading the files via OLEDB and then working with the data outside of excel** then you can install the [Access Connectivity Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) for free. This basically the components needed to read various Office data in a need 'service only' package (or driver if you prefer). I don't if allows random access at the cell level, but I know it does allow you to run OLEDB queries over the .XLS file. We use for loading .XLS files into databases.

All of these come with different licensing restrictions and costs. And without any of your use cases, all I can suggest is that you consider that Excel is a chunky set of application components and to use them you need to understand exactly how your application and they will function/interact and also their limitations in any particular deployment scenario you envisage.

**Edit:
Further info: If you are running on a 64 server and are using a 32 bit application then the only way I could ACE to work was to install the ACE 2007 and not 2010 version**

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to read file content you can use Csv format, wich I think will be the easiest way you can read excel files in your server. you can 'save as' a excel file into *.csv. A csv file is no more than a text file wich is written this way(comma delimited):

"column1","column2","column3"

So now all you just have to do is read a text file.

[CVS Files](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenXml or ClosedXml - they work on the server