# Can't read xlsx file using OLEDB in C#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have a website that users can upload an xlsx-file to. My application then reads the content and does some stuff.
But when some users upload a file my application can't read the content with the error 'External table is not in the expected format'

One of the users is using Excel 2007. The weird thing is that if I open his file with my Excel 2013 and save it without changing anything, it works fine.

This is the oledb connectionstring:

```
OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
        Data Source=" + filepath + @";
        Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
```

And I have installed Microsofts AccessDatabaseEngine.

Another thing is that if I rename the newly saved file (Excel 2013) to *.zip then I can open it with rar/explorer, but if I try to do the same with his file (Excel 2007) I can't open it.

Edit: I now installed Office 2007 on my PC so I have both 2007 and 2013.
I then did the zip-trial and, with the same file, every time I saved with 2007, I couldn't open with winrar but when I saved with 2013 it worked fine. I did this multiple times with the same file back and forth. Same result.

Edit2: Did as suggested and used EPPlus instead. Same result. Works fine when saved with Excel 2013 but doesn't work when saved with Excel 2007.

Comment: Is it maybe possible that the file is not a real `xlsx`  document, but instead just a HTML document containing a table, that was just renamed to `xlsx`? (Some applications generate excel files like that - MS Excel is able to open these files, but trying to read that with OleDB or using OpenXML fails). Maybe try opening the file using notepad and see if it is actually a HTML instead of an `xlsx` document.

Comment: Just tried opening it with Notepad++ and it was all gibberish, so pretty sure that is not the case. Also the document has some functionality that, as far as I know, is not possible with it being saved as HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Excel file on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157180/reading-excel-file-on-the-server)

Comment: Microsoft Office was not designed to be run on a web server. Don't use OLE DB in a website's server-side code.

Comment: I would suggest looking for a nuget package to install such as EPPlus

Comment: @krillgar Not the same error, so not a duplicate. Plus it's not at all the same error-description I'm giving.

Comment: @Neophear My non-automatically generated comment about not using OLE DB still stands, and gives a reason why it's a bad idea to do what you're doing. The duplicate I marked it as is just the first that came up with a similar explanation in the answers.

Comment: @RichardBoyce and krillgar I did as suggested and used EPPlus instead of OLE DB. Same result. Updated my question. Although I will use EPPlus in the future because of how easy it is, so thanks for showing me that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling I came upon the answer which is posted here:
[Error reading xlsx (2007) file in EPPLUS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779054/error-reading-xlsx-2007-file-in-epplus)

It appears that there is an error when the document is password-protected and saved with Excel 2007. When I removed all protection and saved it again (still in Excel 2007), it worked.